# Why are WordUtil instances a bad idea?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I was poking through the Apache Commons java docs when I found [this](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html):

> WordUtils instances should NOT be constructed in standard programming.

Why?

I am a novice programmer, so perhaps it's the "standard" bit that is tripping me up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WordUtils` is a static utility class. It provides a bunch of static methods that each performs a useful task, but there is no need to ever create an *instance* of WordUtils, because the class stores no state.

You can invoke static methods directly upon the class:

```
WordUtils.doSomething();
```

There is no need to create an instance:

```
WordUtils wu =  new WordUtils();
wu.doSomething();
```

Although this will *work*, creating the WordUtils object (using `new`) is pointless.

If all this `static` stuff makes no sense, try the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

As the javadoc for the constructor mentions:

> WordUtils instances should NOT be constructed in standard programming.
>   Instead, the class should be used as WordUtils.wrap("foo bar", 20);.
>
> **This constructor is public to permit tools that require a *JavaBean*
>   instance to operate**.

You can further notice that all public methods of the class are **static**, there are no instance methods.
The constructor is just there to adhere to the [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) standard.

When creating so called *"utility"* classes, you'll notice that there usually is no need for state, and thus the classes only have static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because all methods are static, there is no benefit to instantiating the class.